# Fetching Outlook e-mail categories from Microsoft Graph

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I want to fetch only a particular category that belongs to an email from Microsoft Graph / Outlook endpoint. But is gives me all the categories which are present in associated email.

[https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/outlook/masterCategories/?$filter = displayName eq 'Red category']

Above link is my query to Microsoft Graph API and I get the following result 
`{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/$metadata#users('1e69674d-b0b3-404e-ae2d-a758569ce83c')/outlook/masterCategories",
    "value": [
        {
            "id": "347a7dcc-6c61-4c93-85a5-eb75f973a77f",
            "displayName": "Red category",
            "color": "preset0"
        },
        {
            "id": "643d45c3-aecb-4fbb-8254-c2520f01cf20",
            "displayName": "Orange category",
            "color": "preset1"
        },
        {
            "id": "d06a692a-9406-4052-9b1e-bc7ae293a4e4",
            "displayName": "Yellow category",
            "color": "preset3"
        },
        {
            "id": "8c3e842d-427f-4480-8459-e3e4e785fa85",
            "displayName": "Green category",
            "color": "preset4"
        },
        {
            "id": "11502440-1912-4de1-afad-c2209178219d",
            "displayName": "Blue category",
            "color": "preset7"
        },
        {
            "id": "f3f1b1ca-b319-4951-9eeb-954a169e3d71",
            "displayName": "Purple category",
            "color": "preset8"
        },
        {
            "id": "1fc2506b-2676-447c-bfa3-44a3a7a2dc2d",
            "displayName": "Important",
            "color": "preset14"
        },
        {
            "id": "8926f11d-23ba-4804-ace7-8ae349f390a6",
            "displayName": "Caution",
            "color": "preset16"
        },
        {
            "id": "60434e45-effa-40d7-b753-705d59ef3440",
            "displayName": "Star",
            "color": "preset2"
        }
    ]
}`

Any ways of filtering the categories through properties like *displayName* ?

Answer (score 0):

Based on official guideline, it supports {id} to filter.

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/outlook/masterCategories/8cefb2b7-8f81-47e3-b6d3-a8e2dd4ac42a
```

https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/api/outlookcategory_get

Comment: Thank you for reply, but their is any other option I just pass the displayName and get the only that category?

Comment: I can't get the ?$filter to work even through the document mentions it supports the OData Query Parameters to help customize the response.

Answer (score 0):

The /me/ normally doesn't return filters for me very well.

Try calling

/users/{id}/outlook/masterCategories?filter=displayName eq 'Red Category'